# How to inject a static field in micronaut 2?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, static, micronaut

I have a factory class that creates an object. In my case, this is ObjectMapper (Jackson).

```
@Factory
public class JacksonFactory {

  @Singleton
  public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper().configure(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
  }

}
```

I want to inject it into a static field of the class:

```
public class JsonString {

  @Inject
  private static ObjectMapper mapper;

  public static String of(Object object) {
    try {
      return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException exception) {
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
  }

}
```

But, it doesn't work that way. I get a NullPointer every time I access the mapper static field. If I make the methods and the field non-static everything works well.

I didn’t find an explanation for this in the documentation, maybe I’m missing something or what is the problem with dependency injection?

Many thanks for the help! :)

*UPDATE*

Ok guys. I am not creating a static class, but creating an object and I want to inject it as a dependency into all objects that will be created. Why is the dependency not injected when I create inheritors of the JsonDto object?

```
@Singleton
public class JsonString {

  @Inject
  private ObjectMapper mapper;

  public String of(Object object) {
    try {
      return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException exception) {
      throw new KyivAirException(exception);
    }
  }

}
```

I thought that every time when creating an object, Micronaut will find this bin in the context and substitute it. But that doesn't seem to be how it works.
I am completely confused -_\

```
public abstract class JsonDto {

  @Inject
  private JsonString jsonString;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return jsonString.of(this);
  }

}
```

Comment: _Don't_ use statics; that's the whole point of dependency injection. Make the mapper (or some other service class containing it) a constructor parameter of wherever needs it.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thank you for your answer, yes, I understand what you are talking about. But in this case, I would not want to inject dependency. I want to move boilerplate logic into a static util class, and use it as needed. Although this is probably a holywar statement :)

Comment: Use a singleton class for your "boilerplate" and inject it whereever its needed, thats what dependency injection is made for+

Comment: @IEE1394 Thanks for the answer, I tried it all the same it doesn’t work - NPE. I had updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i suggest try something like that:

First create your object converter which will take of converting the objects

```
@Singleton
public class ObjectConverter (private ObjectMapper mapper) {

  public String of(Object object) {
    try {
      return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException exception) {
      throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
  }

}
```

Than have your dto like that (i prefer constructor injection over @inject)

```
public abstract class MyDto(private ObjectConverter converter)  {
    
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return converter.of(this);
  }

}
```

And finally your service, taking care of the dtos

```
@Singleton
public class MyDtoService(private ObjectConverter mapper) {

  public String get(Long id) {
  // TODO get the object from somewhere
  return mapper.of(dto)
  }

}
```

If we are talking about a dto that comes from the database i suggest something like that

```
interface MyJsonDbDto {
   String decode(ObjectConverter mapper) {
     return mapper.of(this)
   }
}

public class MyDbDto implements MyJsonDbDto{

}
```

and the service therefore

```
public class MyDbDtoService(private ObjectConverter converter, private MyDbDtoRepository repository)
      public String get(Long id) {
  // TODO get the object from repository
  return dto.decode(converter)
  }
}
```

hope that helps and sorry i am mainly in kotlin, therefore my java is a little rusty ;-)

EDIT:

regarding your comment, i have an ugly idea, which could be considered as a some kind of intermediate solution for your refactoring process

create the service like that (use context, cause its not lazy loaded like a singleton)

```
@Context
public class MyDtoService {

  public static ObjectConverter mapper;

  public MyDtoService(ObjectConverter mapper) {
     MyDtoService.mapper = mapper;
  }

}
```

after that you can access it whithin your dto

```
public class MyDto {
    
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return MyDtoService.mapper.of(this);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, but unfortunately in my case it did not work: * (Perhaps I will clarify how the problem looks now:

Comment: Dto comes to me from httpClient in which I need to use the service to override toString. But, since I cannot inject the service into Dto, because the object is not created by DI Micronaut, I thought to put the service into a static field and, according to the logic, it is injected. But, this does not work and I will have to create an object in a static field via new. And in the end there will be two objects in memory, although it is a singleton.

Comment: added you some suggestion in the answer